# How to use <Link> tag in pure Typescript(.ts)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have a function which returns me an URL

```
export function getUrl(params) {
  return <Link to={params}>{params.value}</Link>
}
```

There is no issue to use it in .tsx file, but how to adjust it for a pure Typescript(.ts)?

I'm new to Typescript and React, still learning :)

Comment: Wouldn't typing the code snippet be exactly the same in either since it's still Typescript? The `.tsx` is just generally used to indicate it's a React component returning JSX. Are you essentially asking how to type this function then?

Comment: You cannot use tags in a normal `.ts` file. `.tsx` is Typescript JSX which allows the use of tags. Just change the file to use `.tsx`. Also your snippet is essentially a function component you might be better off naming your function with a capital ( such as `Url` ) so that you can use it as a tag i.e. `<Url {...params} />`

Comment: `<Link/>` is JSX syntax, so it has to be in a `.tsx` file (though that might depend on your compiler settings?).  If `Link` is a function component, you can call it using function syntax `Link({to: params, children: params.value})` and that would work in `.ts` file.  But this is silly and you should just use the `.tsx` extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSX is just syntactic sugar for function calls to `React.createElement`. So *in theory*, you could use something like:

```js
import React, { ReactChild } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export function getUrl(params: object & { value: ReactChild | ReactChild[] }) {
  return React.createElement(Link, { to: params }, params.value);
}
```

... but, as per the comments on your question, it's probably simpler just to use a .tsx extension.

What *I suspect* you're really after is the [`generatePath` function](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/generatePath) from react-router.